# Getting the total value in all the rows

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular, ssas-2012

I'm using the calculation below to calculate the sum of the amount for `accounts >= 200`
And the problem I have is when I visualize Account with Account total with excel, it gives me the total amount in all accounts.
How can I solve this?`

`Account total:= CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[amount]),'Table'[Type]= "ABC",'Table'[account] >=200)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using:

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[amount] ),
    FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Type] = "ABC" && 'Table'[account] >= 200 )
)
```

The difference is that your current formula is equivalent to:

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[amount] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Type] = "ABC" && 'Table'[account] >= 200 )
)
```

i.e. identical to that which I give apart from the crucial difference that it applies an (in your case implicit) `ALL` to the table prior to filtering. This implicit `ALL` will override any filters you may be applying externally.

Answer (score 1):

@Jos is mostly correct but there are some small inaccuracies.

This code

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[amount] ),
    'Table'[Type] = "ABC",
    'Table'[account] >= 200
)
```

[is equivalent to](https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2010/01/03/how-calculate-works-in-dax/)

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[amount] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table'[Type] ), 'Table'[Type] = "ABC" ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table'[account] ), 'Table'[account] >= 200 )
)
```

not

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[amount] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Type] = "ABC" && 'Table'[account] >= 200 )
)
```

In particular, if you had a filter on, say, `'Table'[Category]`, this would be preserved in the former but not in the latter since `ALL ( 'Table' )` removes filters on all of the columns, not just `[Type]` and `[account]`.

---

I propose the following two nearly equivalent solutions, which are slightly more computationally efficient than filtering an entire table:

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[amount] ),
    FILTER ( VALUES ( 'Table'[Type] ), 'Table'[Type] = "ABC" ),
    FILTER ( VALUES ( 'Table'[account] ), 'Table'[account] >= 200 )
)
```

or

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[amount] ),
    KEEPFILTERS ( 'Table'[Type] = "ABC" ),
    KEEPFILTERS ( 'Table'[account] >= 200 )
)
```

---

More on KEEPFILTERS: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-keepfilters-in-dax/